# The second parameter in my exported function is undefined

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and this is making no sense to me. The payload parameter is undefined and I dont see why:

```
const addEvent = async ( id, payload ) => {
   console.log( payload );
   // .... other async stuff
}

module.exports = {
    addEvent
}
```

different file:

```
const eventbus = require('../lib/eventbus')

module.exports = {
    handler: async ctx => {
        console.log( ctx.state.webhook )
        await database.addEvent( ctx.state.webhook.payload.id, ctx.state.webook )
    }
}
```

In the console, when the handler is called it displays ctx.state.webhook with all the right details in. But the console.log in addEvent logs payload as undefined. I don't see why at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical mistake of programming! Spelling :) corrected the same below.

```
const eventbus = require('../lib/eventbus')

module.exports = {
    handler: async ctx => {
        console.log( ctx.state.webhook )
        await database.addEvent( ctx.state.webhook.payload.id, ctx.state.webhook )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one important stage in learning to code. :) Good luck!